# how to find the index of a random number in a list (length of list 50) in <=25 chances?

Tags: math, discrete-mathematics

I have a tricky question. I have a list of random numbers ranging from 0 to 49 and there are 50 people. each person has been assigned with a number randomly in from 0 to 49. now the problem is, everyone needs to find the index of their assigned number in the list (eg: if you were assigned with 10 and need to find the index of 10 in the list). everyone has at max 25 chances and everybody needs to find the index number of their "assigned number" in the list within this 25 chances (everyone gets 25 chances maximum. everybody needs to win for the team win, if atleast one fails everyone will fail.

What will be the strategy that the team should follow in order to make everyone win (i.e., team win)?

Comment: Interesting question, but you haven't specified a programming language, or showed an attempt.  Probably better suited for https://math.stackexchange.com

Comment: Why would you need to specify a programming language either in the question or the answer?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is not about programming.

Answer (score 1):

You need 49 x 25 questions in the worst case (if 49 people have asked if they are at index 0 and got the answer “no” then #50 knows he or she is at Index 0 and need not ask).

The trick is that the players who answered fewer questions can ask whether a friend #i is at index #j, and tell the friend if they are,  so the questions are evenly distributed between all 50.

Answer (score 0):

This appears to be the [100 prisoners problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/100_prisoners_problem). There is a strategy that will succeed with more than 30% probability, described in the Wiki page.